# How to use select statement in CASE WHEN ELSE statement in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a table `USER` with these contents:

```
 USER_ID   User_Name   City   zip   PR_USER_ID
--------- ----------- ------ ----- ------------
 101       AAA         PPP    123   101
 102       BBB         QQQ    345   101
 103       CCC         RRR    567   NULL
 104       FFF         SSS    789   102
```

I need to add a query inside the procedure for display the `User_Name`:

```
CASE WHEN PR_USER_ID IS NULL
     THEN 'NO_PR_USER'   
     ELSE ... get the `User_Name`
              corressponding to USER.USERID = USER.PR_USER_ID
```

Like as I need:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN USR.PR_USER_ID IS NULL THEN 'NO PR_USER' 
    ELSE (
      SELECT USR.NAME
      FROM USER USR
      WHERE USR.USER_ID = USR.PR_USR_ID
    ) PRIMARY_USER_NAME
  END
```

Using this query I am getting the `USER_NAME`:

```
SELECT
  PRIMARY_USER.NAME AS PRIMARY_USER_NAME
FROM USER SECONDARY_USER
INNER JOIN USER PRIMARY_USER ON PRIMARY_USER.USER_id = SECONDARY_USER.PR_USER_ID;
```

but I need the Output like this:

```
  PR_USER_ID   PRIMARY_USER_NAME
 ------------ -------------------
  101          AAA
  101          AAA
  NULL         No_PR_USER
  102          BBB
```

How to get my result in `CASE WHEN ELSE` statement or any other way?

Please give me an example.

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: i am using only Oracle11g

Answer (score 3):

You should use a (left) outer join to solve such case. `NVL`/`COALESCE` will take care of replacing NULL by some hard coded value. Something *like* that:

```
SELECT T...., T...., NVL(USR.NAME, 'NO PR_USER' )
FROM USER T
LEFT JOIN USER USR
ON USR.USER_ID=T.PR_USER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try following query:-

```
SELECT CASE WHEN USR.PR_USER_ID IS NULL THEN 'NO PR_USER' 
ELSE USR.NAME END AS PRIMARY_USER_NAME 
FROM USER USR 
WHERE USR.USER_ID=USR.PR_USR_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if its worth for you.
`select user_id,case  when pr_user_id IS NOT NULL then user_name
             else 'NO PR_USER'
             end as primary_user_name
from user_name;`

It displays the below result 
   [image]

Comment: But i need the Output like this:

     PR_USER_ID     PRIMARY_USER_NAME
      101                       AAA
      101                       AAA
      NULL                    No_PR_USER
      102                       BBB

Comment: can you please provide me in tabular format as I am not able to rectify your output?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you try with below query.

```
select decode(pr_user_id,null,null,user_id),case  when pr_user_id IS NOT NULL then user_name
             else 'NO PR_USER'
             end as primary_user_name
from test_2;
```

```
101     AAA
102     BBB
null    NO PR_USER
104     FFF
```